# Open Source/Free ASP.NET Webcontrol for Document Repository

Tags: asp.net, open-source, document-repository

Is anyone aware of a good open source document repository webcontrol for ASP.NET? I'd like to give users the ability to upload files, create folders, etc. in particular paths on the web server.  I want a full user interface so just the WebDAV API or a partial solution like Uploadify is not enough.

Comment: Something like ckfinder ? http://ckfinder.com/demo

Comment: Actually that's a great option despite not being Open Source. Please put this as an answer as I may select it despite the fact it's a paid solution.  It appears to be a good option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out KCFinder: http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/

It is a **free open source** alternative to CKFinder.

I've worked with this on a corporate intranet site and it has served us beautifully.

Comment: +1 for this one that I didnt know it, how ever this is not apear to work with asp.net !

Comment: There is no asp.net connector for kcfinder sadly. Would that be interesting to users? I'm thinking of forking it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand the question, but there are lots of free (and even more commercial) file manager controls for ASP.NET, e.g: [essential objects](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOWeb/FileExplorer.aspx), [IZWebFileManager](http://www.izwebfilemanager.com/demo/default.aspx), [ASP.NET AJAX Style Folder Explorer](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/hwo_to_create_an_aspnet_ajax_s.html).

Personally I'm using the (commercial) RadControls suite by telerik, which also contains a [file explorer control](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx).